# continue code in next line

Tags: excel, vba, loops

I have the following code:

```
Sub rangeSelect()

    Dim r1 As Range, r2 As Range, multiAreaRange As Range, lcopytorow As Long
    Worksheets("data").Activate
    Set r1 = Range("c9:i9")
    Set r2 = Range("m9:af9")
    Set multiAreaRange = Union(r1, r2)

    LCopyToRow = 2

    If Range("L9").Value = "yes" Then

        multiAreaRange.Select
        Selection.Copy
        Sheets("drop").Select
        Rows(CStr(LCopyToRow) & ":" & CStr(LCopyToRow)).Select
        ActiveSheet.Paste

        LCopyToRow = LCopyToRow + 1

        Sheets("data").Select

    End If

End Sub
```

my purpose is to copy the selected ranges into another worksheet called "drop" only if there is "yes" in each corresponding L column. The code works fine for the first item in the table. However, I would need to duplicate it for the whole table (some 3800 rows). I want to avoid copying the entire row but rather only copy the defined ranges as stated above. I assume I would have to define a loop through which the code can jump along,but I am not sure how to do it. Hope my explanation makes sense, new to vba but learning quickly. Any help would be highly appreciated. Thanks guys.

Comment: If you were to do this by hand, would you apply a Filter to column L to only show "Yes" entries then copy the results to the "data" sheet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are on the right track, you simply need to generalize the example you provided through the use of a for loop and a variable.

For loops basically work like this

```
For [some variable] = [starting number] to [ending number]
    [Run some code while variable equals current value]
Next
```

Essentially you will want to wrap your entire code inside a for loop so that it can evaluate each row, one-by-one. The only thing you want outside the loop are your `Dim` declarations and `LCopyToRow = 2` so that they do not reset on each iteration of the loop.

You can set variables by saying something like `Dim i as Long`. It appears you want to start your for loop by setting `i = 9` for the 9th row and looping through to your last row of the original sheet. If the row will be constant you can simply set it to that value, but if it changes making a "lastrow" variable would be a good idea.

For example, the first line within your for loop would be: `Set r1 = Sheets("data").Range("c" & i & ":i" & i)`, and then you would follow a similar format while placing the variable into your other statements.

One other thing I would recommend is declare your sheet in front of your range, as I did in the example above, and then drop the select statements from the code. This can help speed up your code it, keep it cleaner, and help prevent errors. Also it will stop the workbook from flipping back and forth between sheets, which can be annoying if you are watching the process run.

For example, instead of:

```
multiAreaRange.Select
Selection.Copy
Sheets("drop").Select
Rows(CStr(LCopyToRow) & ":" & CStr(LCopyToRow)).Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
```

You could simply say something like:

```
multiAreaRange.copy destination:=Sheets("drop").Rows(CStr(LCopyToRow) & ":" & CStr(LCopyToRow))
```

Edit: I have this working for me in a sample workbook:

```
Sub test()
    Dim r1 As Range, _
    r2 As Range, _
    multiAreaRange As Range, _
    lcopytorow As Long, _
    i As Long

    lcopytorow = 2

    For i = 9 To 100
        Set r1 = Sheets("data").Range("c" & i & ":i" & i)
        Set r2 = Sheets("data").Range("m" & i & ":af" & i)
        Set multiAreaRange = Union(r1, r2)

        If Sheets("data").Range("L" & i).Value = "yes" Then

            multiAreaRange.Copy Destination:=Sheets("drop").Rows(lcopytorow & ":" & lcopytorow)

            lcopytorow = lcopytorow + 1

        End If
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for your elaborate comment and explanation. I am just trying to work in your changes. I am getting an error message (syntax error) for the last part: multiAreaRange.Copy(Sheets("drop").Rows(CStr(lcopytorow) & ":" & CStr(lcopytorow))   I am sure I'm missing something obvious here...

Comment: Try `multiAreaRange.copy destination:=Sheets("drop").Rows(CStr(LCopyToRow) & ":" & CStr(LCopyToRow))`. I generally have better luck with stating things explicitly, than hoping VBA understands its own rules

Comment: The first answer suggested above works but you have a point with speeding it up and preventing the workbook from flipping. Still doesn't seem to work with the last change for me however...

Comment: I have edited the original answer to include a sample sub which is working for me.

Comment: Tried your edit for my sample file and it works now indeed. Great to have the workbook not flipping anymore. Thanks very much for your help!

Answer (score 2):

Please correct me if I misunderstood your question, but I think you only need to index the row number in your definitions:

```
Dim r1 As Range, r2 As Range, multiAreaRange As Range, copytorow As Long
Worksheets("data").Activate

LCopyToRow = 2

For j = 9 To 3800 'repeat this 3791 times, or use Range("c9").End(xlDown).Row to get the last line as suggested by chancea (definitely more flexible)

    Set r1 = Range("c" & j & ":i" & j)
    Set r2 = Range("m" & j & ":af" & j)
    Set multiAreaRange = Union(r1, r2)

    If Range("L" & j).Value = "yes" Then

        multiAreaRange.Select 
        Selection.Copy
        Sheets("drop").Select
        Rows(CStr(LCopyToRow) & ":" & CStr(LCopyToRow)).Select
        ActiveSheet.Paste

        LCopyToRow = LCopyToRow + 1

        Sheets("data").Select

    End If

Next j
```

The above is the same code you had before, but instead of running on line 9 only it's running from line 9 to line 3800 (custom your values as you prefer, of course). Please note I'm assuming the previous code is working fine for line 9, so it is applicable to all the other lines.

**EDIT suggested by chancea:**

You don't need to select ranges and sheets everytime, it would just make a big useless mess if run over 3800 lines because you would see the screen continuously jumping from one place to the other. But I don't touch the code, I let you update as you prefer.

Comment: Couldn't you get the last row used instead of hardcoding the 3800?  And wouldn't it be better to get rid of those `Select`s?

Comment: @chancea right for both, but I assumed the user didn't want to touch his code but just know how to re-use it through the lines. Happy to accept your edit, if you propose it!

Comment: @MatteoNNZ thanks very much for your answer and assistance. The proposed edit doesn't seem to work. It copies line 9 again but nothing underneath. If you guys prefer changing my proposal (e.g. getting the last row), I'd be happy to take this as well, it probably will be a more intelligent solution than the one initially created.

Comment: [DON'T USE `SELECT`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba-macros)

Comment: This answer looked correct to me so I did not answer. I observed that a variable named `copytorow` is DIM'ed, but `LCopyToRow` is used. Could there be an issue with these getting mixed up?

Comment: @laylarenee indeed lcopyrow is used but I had changed this already before my comment in the code so that wasn't the issue (edited this in the original question now as well).

Comment: Is Cell `L10` equals to "yes"? (If it is not, then row 10 would not be copied)

Comment: I doesn't equal "yes". L 13 is the next that does.

Comment: @simon, it was a stupid mistake i did. The variable LCopyToRow was inside the loop so it was being initialized each time. Try it now, it should be better.